Retrieve parent fields from SObject with DataBase.query()
I am a little bit confused. Need to retrieve all the fields from this query
    String soql = 'SELECT OwnerId, Owner.name, Owner.email FROM ' +
        victim.getSObjectType() +
        ' WHERE Id = :victim';
SObject record = Database.query(soql);
//system.debug(record.owner); -- this throws an error
system.debug(record);

but always get an error. What did i miss?

The issue was easy to see this time, but it's never a bad idea to include the text of the error you're getting, verbatim.

SObject is a cumbersome type to work with. Since it needs to be able to represent any specific SObject type, it has basically no fields that you can access using dot notation.
Instead, you need to use methods from the SObject class like .get(), .put(), and be prepared to do a lot of typecasting and null checking.
In this case, you'll want to use the getSObject() method (passing in 'owner'). Then you should do a simple typecast to User to make it easier to work with elsewhere in your logic.
